# I have created a module named get_squares. I have import the module successfully but when I try to run it I get the error "Module object not Callable"

Tags: python, import, module, callable

The file get_squares.py includes the following function:

```
def get_squares(numbers):
squares = [number**2 for number in numbers]
print(squares)
```

I can import the module get_squares but when trying to run it receive the error:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

I looked to see how to troubleshoot and tried:

```
from get_squares import get_squares
```

This does not work as I get the error:
cannot import name 'get_squares' from 'get_squares'

Comment: You can't run a module. You can run a function. You need to define a function insute the module:
def get_squares(args): ...

Answer (score 0):

To test, I created get_squares.py. Make sure it looks like this with the proper indent.

```
"""
Module: get_squares.py
"""


def get_squares(numbers):
    squares = [number**2 for number in numbers]
    print(squares)
```

Then a script to test the module.

```
from get_squares import get_squares

get_squares((25,)) # Test with a tuple with one element.

get_squares((3,8,25)) # Test with a tuple with multiple elements.
```

Output

```
[625]
[9, 64, 625]
```